# find Number of connected components of $Y$?

Tags: general-topology

Let $Q,Q^c$ denotes  be the set of all rational and irrational numbers in $\mathbb {R}$. $Y=\mathbb {R^2}\setminus(Q×Q^C )$ with the usual subspace topology of $\mathbb {R^2}$.find  Number of connected components of $Y$?

My answer   :  i thinks  $Y = \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \cup  \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. Since $Y$ is covered by lines in both coordinate directions,  it is path connected. so  $Y$ has one connected component.

is  its correct/incorrect ??

Pliz tell me

Comment: Subspace topology? Do you mean $\setminus$ instead of $/$? And wouldn't $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R\cup \Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ simply be $\Bbb R\times \Bbb R$ again, with nothing removed?

Comment: i mean  \  @HagenvonEitzen,,sorry sir   wites  mistakes...i edit now

Comment: I think you mean $\Bbb R\times \Bbb Q\cup \Bbb Q^c\times \Bbb R$. Then, yes, this shows that $Y$ is path-connected.

Comment: that mean  how  many connected  components  are there  in  Y ???@HagenvonEitzen sir

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Notice that

$Y =\mathbb{R}^2\backslash(\mathbb{Q}\times\mathbb{Q}^c) = (\mathbb{R}\times (\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q}^c))\cup((\mathbb{R}\backslash \mathbb{Q})\times \mathbb{Q}^c) = (\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{Q})\cup(\mathbb{Q}^c\times\mathbb{Q}^c).$

So, if $y=(a,b)\in Y$ and $b\in \mathbb{Q}^c$, then $a\in\mathbb{Q}^c$ and $\{y\}$ is the connected component of $y$.

If, $y'= (a,b)\in Y$ and $b\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $a$ can be any real number, so $\{(t,b),\ t\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is the connected componet of $y'$.

Comment: I think this is incorrect, since the space is path connected