# Connected component of $A=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus(\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}^c)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I showed in a previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931515/understanding-a-mathbbr2-setminus-mathbbq-times-mathbbqc) that
$$A=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus(\mathbb{Q}\times \mathbb{Q}^c)$$
looks something like 
$$\{(a,b)\;|\;a\in \mathbb{Q}^c, b\in \mathbb{R}\}\cup \{(a,b)\;|\;a\in \mathbb{R}, b\in \mathbb{Q}\}$$

*I want to find the connected components of $A$?*

**My Efforts**

I have two ways to approach in mind. Please have a look and point out the errors.

(1)

Take $a\in \mathbb{Q}^c$ then we are free to chose the second component so connected component of any point whose first coordinate is irrational will be a vertical line $x=a$

and if $a\in \mathbb{Q}$, the only choice for $b$ is that $b$ is also a rational number. So connected component of a point whose both coordinate are rational is just a singleton set.

Method 2

Take $b$ in $\mathbb{Q}^c$ then $a$ also belong to $\mathbb{Q}^c$, so connected component of such points is just the point itself, that is a sigleton set.

And if $b$ is in $\mathbb{Q}$ then we are free to chose $a$ to be any real. Connected component in this case is horizontal lines.

**Why I am getting different connected components? I am confused.**

Comment: the two reasoning are both wrong, but if you unite them, you get the right answer

Comment: @Exodd Oh I see!! So connected components are vertical lines, horizontal lines and singletons (corresponding to $(a,b)$ where both coordinate are rational, and similarly where both are irrational)

Comment: no, check the nswer below

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2781834/find-number-of-connected-components-of-y?noredirect=1#comment6055941_2931600  @Exodd Can you please look at the solution posted in this question. His solution is quite similar to mine.

Comment: it is incorrect

Comment: @Exodd thanks a lot for your time. I get the point that since the space is connected, talking about connected component does not make any sense

Comment: well, it has a sense. It means it has only one connected component, that is the whole space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $A$ is (path) connected: For $(x,y)$ in the set, either $\{x\}\times \Bbb R$ or  $\Bbb R\times\{y\}$ is completely contained in $A$ and intersetcs the main diagonal $\{\,(t,t)\mid t\in\Bbb R\,\}$ that also belongs to $A$. Along this horizontal or vertical line plus the diagonal, we readily find a path in $A$ from $(x,y)$ to $(0,0)$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2781834/find-number-of-connected-components-of-y?noredirect=1#comment6055941_2931600  Have a look at this question.  I just found it. So is the solution posted in the linked question incorrect ?